# Nuxt Plugin not adding google maps script tag

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am experiencing an issue with my Nuxt plugin, specifically the `googleMap.client.ts` plugin. The plugin's main purpose is to add the necessary script tag for the Google Maps API during the initial page load.
 However, upon the first-page load, the plugin does not seem to be functioning properly. It is only after reloading the page that the script tag is added and the plugin starts working as intended.
Here is the code for my plugin

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  let config = useRuntimeConfig();

  if (window.location.origin !== "<my-origin>") {
    config.googleMapKey = config.googleMapDevKey;
  }

  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${config.googleMapKey}&libraries=places,drawing,geometry&callback=initMap`;
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

I think there is some issue with the `useRunTimeConfig`. How do I make it so that it loads on the initial page load and does not have to reload that page?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `useHead` composable instead of using plain javascript?

Basic example would be like this.

**Note:** private runtime configs will return undefined in the client. To fix that, you need to move your API key to public.

`~/plugins/map.client.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    let config = useRuntimeConfig()
    useHead({
        script: [
            {
                src: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${config.public.GOOGLE_MAP_KEY}&libraries=places,drawing,geometry&callback=initMap`,
                async: true,
            }, {
                src: '/scripts/map-init.js',
                async: true
            }
        ]
    })

})
```

`~/public/scripts/map-init.js`

```js
let map

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map" ), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8,
    } )
}

window.initMap = initMap
```

The protection of your API key can be configured in the Google cloud.
[image]

Expected output
[image]